# Express.JS: Cannot post /url or redirecting to /url?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm experiencing an error in my app that I am trying to fix, where either express will give me 'Cannot post /login' or will redirect me to a /url? page.

I've tried to fix this, so here is my code:

index2.ejs:

```
<html>
  <%- include('partials/header.ejs'); -%>
  <body>
    <div id="top-block">
          <form id="login" method="post">
            <label>Create A Display Name...</label>
              <input type="text" id="name">
              <br><br>
              <label>Create A Profile Picture...</label>
              <input id="pfp" type="text"> 
              <br><br>
              <label>Create A Bio...</label>
              <input id="bio" type="text">
              <br><br>
              <input type="submit" formmethod="post">
              <button onclick="window.location = '/'">Back to main page</button>
          </form>

        <script>
          var user = localStorage.get('user')

          var base = "";
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file)
   reader.onloadend = function() {
     globalThis.base = reader.result.toString()
//     document.write(globalThis.base)
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
  }   

          $('#login').submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          localStorage.setItem("uname", $('#name').val())
          localStorage.setItem("pfp", $('#pfp').val())

          localStorage.setItem("url", '/profile?pfp=' + $('#pfp').val() + '&disName=' + $('#name').val() + '&genName=' + localStorage.getItem('user') + '&bio=' + $('#bio').val())
      })
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index2.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index2.ejs");
});

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index.ejs");
});

module.exports = router;
```

What my code SHOULD do is redirect to '/' (the index page) when i press the button, but instead, it either says it cannot post /login, or redirects me to /login?. So would any of you have any ideas, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `/api` route is missing in your backend code. Please add that. And also, your frontend `<form></form>` is not having `action` attribute.

Comment: could you explain what the route file would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have two routes that use the same route ("/") and the same HTTP method ("GET")in index2.js.

This will cause conflicts. Make sure you define one path to view the index2.js page and another path to redirect to the index.js page.

Then Modify your form by adding the action attribute to specify the route to send the POST request.

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="/login">
   <!The rest of your form-->
</form>
```

The rest of your form, too many things together, fix these things and then let's see how it goes....

Comment: I added a post method route in the route for the homepage, and fixed a few things so it would still update the localStorage items, thanks!